# How to access perticular data in excel sheet

Tags: java, jsp

actually i want to fetch a particular data from excel sheet (.xls and .xlsx) like i have a column name email in my excel sheet and i want to fetch only that column. This is my code which is already i wrote but this is fetching all the details.Sorry for my grammar.

package readfile;

```
 import java.io.File;

 import jxl.Cell;
 import jxl.Sheet;
 import jxl.Workbook;
 public class reademail {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {


        File f=new File("C:\\Users\\LQRP0023\\Desktop\\try.xls");

        Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);

        Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);

        int row=s.getRows();

        int col=s.getColumns();


         for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
         {

            for(int j=0;j<col;j++)

             {
                Cell c=s.getCell(j,i);

                System.out.print(c.getContents());
             }

          System.out.println("");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       } }}
```

Comment: If you want to get the answer you need, you should add a sample xls file content and your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [CellReference](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) utility class to help you out.

You can then do something like:

```
 Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("MyInterestingSheet");

 CellReference ref = new CellReference("B12");
 Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
 if (r != null) {
    Cell c = r.getCell(ref.getCol());
 }
```

That will let you find the cell at a given Excel-style reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `Cell` type and call the appropriate method to get the value, e.g.:

```
switch(cell.getCellType()){
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        String stringValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;

    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        Number numericValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;
}
```

For cell with `Date`, you can use `HSSFDateUtil` class to check the date formatted `cell` and get the value, e.g.:

```
if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
    Date dateValue = cell.getDateCellValue();
}
```